# I don't really understand what my lecturer is getting at here - lecture notes on computing prime numbers with Java

Tags: java, arraylist, primes

> A naive algorithm for computing prime
> numbers exists. For example, you could
> use a while loop to check that c % i
> != 0 for all positive integer i such
> that i > 1 and i < c.
>
> However, it is
> not dicult to see that a much better
> method is making sure that c % p != 0
> for all prime numbers p such that p <
> c. Using the primes in your ArrayList
> this is easy as pie. Note again that
> this suggests that you use a while
> loop.

I've tried to implement both of these methods, and while I get the first one, checking that c % i != 0, I don't understand the second piece of information saying a better algorithm would be to use c % p !=0. Would this not mean I would have to know all prime numbers to compute the prime number ?

What I have at the moment is as follows :

```
  public static void isPrime(int candidateNo) {
while (i <= candidateNo/2) {
  if (candidateNo%i==0 && i!=1) {
    return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}
```

}

which works, though is woefully inefficient. I am using the function to create an arraylist of prime numbers (if the function returns true, the number is added to the arraylist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since you are creating a list of *all* the prime numbers anyway, when you check if a number c is prime, you already have all *smaller* prime numbers in your list. Right?

So, instead of testing if *any* number smaller than `candidateNo/2` divides your candidate, you only test if any *prime number* smaller than `candidateNo/2` divides your candidate.

So, instead of iterating from `i = 2 to candidateNo/2`, you iterate over the elements of your array list. To this end, this array list should of course be accessible from your isPrime function, so either pass it as an argument or have it as a public static element of your main class.

Comment: You don't need to check all the numbers up to candidateNo/2, only the numbers up to sqrt( candidateNo ).

Answer (score 0):

Any number that is not a prime number can be broken down into prime number factors.

Example:

```
15 = 3 * 5
24 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3
```